# How to find the row and column of a specific element in a multidimensional array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array 8x8 array which is supposed to represent a checkerboard.

```
 var board = [['RS', 'H',  'RS', 'H',  'RS', 'H',  'RS', 'H'],
          ['BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS'],
          ['RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS'],
          ['BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS'],
          ['RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS'],
          ['BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS'],
          ['RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS'],
          ['F', ' RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS']
 ];
```

I want to get the element F's row and column number I am trying to use a 4 loop

```
 function getF(board) {
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if(board[i][j] == 'F'{

     return {row:1, col:j};
```

How do I do this to get the indexes of all H elements?

Comment: you need some array to store the result, each element is an object like `{row: x, col: y}`

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you want to find the location of F or are you trying to locate all H entries?

Comment: did you even try your own function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your function like:

```
 function getCharIndexes(board, char) {
    var i, j, collection = [];
    for (i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        if(board[i][j] == char) {
            collection.push({row:1, col:j}); // should be {row: i, col: j}
        }
      }
    }
    return collection;
  }
```

To get 'F' call:  `getCharIndexes(board, 'F');`

To get 'H' call:  `getCharIndexes(board, 'H');`

etc.

Comment: This will not return what you want, since it is returning a position object with a fixed row of 1 for every match of the `char` parameter. It should be `collection.push({row:i, col:j})` instead

Comment: @RafaelEyng yes, I doubt it's the problem of copying the OP's code, `1` here should be `i`.

Comment: @RafaelEyng Hi, yes I just copy from OP's code, but now I added comment also.

Comment: How can I compare the rows and columns from H and F?

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your code. Besides that, this will do:

```
 function getIndexesOf(matrix, obj) {
    var i, j;
    var ret = []
    for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      var line = matrix[i];
      for (j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
        if(board[i][j] == obj) {
          ret.push({row: i, col: j})
        }
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

This way, you can call it passing what object you want to find (as your 'H'):

```
getIndexesOf(board, 'H');
```

Note that:

1. you are using literal values in your for loops. It would be better to use the length of the matrix and of the lines that you pass in.
2. in your example you are returning `{row:1, col:j}`. That is not correct, not even for your purposes in the example. In that case you would return `{row:i, col:j}`, because `i` holds the row number, and doesn't make sense to return a fixed row number of 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are missing your closures for your `if` statement and `for` loops, I assume that this is a copy/paste issue.

Next, I don't think your `getF` function is working, because you are returning the column as `j`, but the row is always 1. To fix that, just return `{ row: i, col: j }` instead.

Finally, the you can use the same loop operation to get all the 'H's, but just keep them in an array, and as you find them, append them using something similar to: `foo.push({ row: i, col: j });`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are almost right:

```
var board = [['RS', 'H',  'RS', 'H',  'RS', 'H',  'RS', 'H'],
    ['BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS'],
    ['RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS'],
    ['BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS'],
    ['RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS'],
    ['BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS'],
    ['RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS'],
    ['F', ' RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS', 'BS', 'RS']];

function getChar(board, c) {
    var i, j, collection = [];
    for (i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        if(board[i][j] == c)
            collection.push({row:i, col:j});
      }
    }
    return collection;
}

console.log(getChar(board, "F"));
console.log(getChar(board, "H"));
```

Comment: How can I compare the rows and columns from H and F? This way I can see if the H should be a specific distance away from the F? For example it must be one row up and one row to the left of the fox?

Comment: @GeorgeCUlloa F is always in 1 position?